# input field not changes on change of dropdown if i insert input field value on form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Input field value change on change of drop down but if i change input field value in form then on change of drop down input field value doesnt change .. this is jquery..

```
$('#Add-DSR-Form').on( 'change', 'tbody td select.cylinder_id', function () {

            var $row  = $(this).parents("tr"),
                index = $row.attr('data-item-index');

            var CylinderID = $(this).val();

            if(CylinderID < 1)
            {
                $row.find('[id="Rate[]"]').attr('value', "").end();
                grandTotal();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                var Action = 'GetCylinderDetail';
                var dataString = 'Action='+ Action +'&CylinderID='+ CylinderID;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/loader_functions.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        //alert(result);
                        //alert(JSON.parse(result));
                        var obj = JSON.parse(result);

                        $row.find('[id="Rate[]"]').attr('value', obj.CylinderPrice).end();
                        grandTotal();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your html also

Comment: @bhumi patel please provide the HTML